# How to solve this peculiar nested for loops exercise?

Tags: c, recursion, for-loop, procedural-programming, repeat

I've been studying C programming for a while and I've stumbled on this exercise I can't seem to solve:

- Write nests of loops that cause the following output to be displayed:

  ```
  0
  01
  012
  0123
  01234
  012345
  01234
  0123
  012
  01
  0
  ```

Until now I've managed to get to the sixth row, but I can't finish the exercise.
This is the code I've written to obtain half of the solution to this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{

int i, j;

for(i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)

    printf("%d", j);
    printf("\n");

 }

return(0);

}
```

The answer had some reasearch effort, was clear; maybe useful for someone studying the same subject, so it was downvoted for no reason.

Comment: what about another nested loop similar to the first one?

Comment: Someone gave the the answer I needed, but it's been deleted.

Comment: maybe because solving homeworks is forbidden at Stack Overflow, you have to follow the suggestions below to solve the problem by yourself

Comment: Weird, I've seen it the FAQ that simply one can't expect to have the answers to every exercise in a book and that questions have got to be specific: that is completely fine. Isn't just hinting trying to teach a cripple to walk while walking like he does? Maybe I should ask different kind of questions, solve exercises with University colleagues. I've still got to understand Stack Overflow philosophy.

Comment: if somebody provides you the full answer, then the whole excercise is worthless. You need to realize by yourself the language mecanisms in order to retain that in your memory in a long-term basis.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares that is true, but I will do a lot of other exercises until I know I've mastered the subject, unable to find a good book to understand the inner working I have to use intuition by studying the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this with a single nested loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getLength(int i) {
    /* Since this is homework, I'll leave this for you to complete. */
    if (i < ?) return ?;
    else return ?;
}

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        int length = getLength(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
             printf("%d", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will work it out until I can understand it completely.

Comment: Be careful with that one, as the question asked for nests, not a nest ;) However, you might get a bonus point for offering it as an extra answer and crediting the source of your inspiration.

Comment: The exercise isn't an assignment, so the objective here is to understand nested for loops, so that won't be a problem... adding in modular programming is a nice one, thanks. (how can I credit as an extra answer?)

Answer (score 1):

There's a clue in the question: "Write **nests** of loops". Count up, then count down.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an exercise I will only hint at a solution, as to learn you really should do this yourself.

1. `for` loops can go in reverse.
2. You can have more than one nested loop.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I needed the final answer because I couldn't understand the inner workings of nested for loops, so I tought I could get more insight by having the complete answer; besides working on the same exercise for the fourth day starts to be painful.

Comment: @AdrianWoodhouse - Take a look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10465121/1583) from [Mark Byers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers) using a single nested loop. If you can understand that, you can be safe in the knowledge that you understand loops.

Comment: Ok thanks; in the end I understood I had a problem discerning the difference between having more than a loop nested one into another, and having different nested loops at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    if(i<=5)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<=i;k++)

        printf("%d",k);
    }
    else if(i>5)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=(10-i);j++)
            printf("%d",j);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

i hope that will help

this is the defualt answer

Answer (score 0):

I thought user should tell till which number to print. so my code is a bit complex.

## include

## include

int main (void)
{

```
   int rows;
   int counter;
   int backward;
   int forward;

printf("Till which number you want to print??");
scanf("%d",&rows);
for(counter=0;counter<=rows;counter++)
    {for(forward=0;forward<=counter;forward++)
        printf("%d",forward);
            printf("\n");
        }

for(counter=rows;counter>=0;counter--)
            {for(backward=0;backward<=counter;backward++)
        printf("%d",backward);
                printf("\n");    
        }

getch();
return 0;
```

}

Thank u !